# NoMigrations exception for django.contrib.x has no migrations

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am trying to migrate a model that has nothing to do with this and as soon as I do migrate it gives me this error:

`NoMigrations: Application '<module 'django.contrib.comments' from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\comments\__init__.pyc' has no migrations.`

I have tried deleting migrations folder and deleting databases but keeps coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be that you have another app named as the last part of the module in this case 'comments' or you have an entry in the database table south_migrationhistory with app_name same as the module.

Found answer here [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/south-users/mdyUypLbOa0/MCFJvMfHdJgJ)

Answer (score 1):

i suggest if you can use django dumpdata , you will get a json file copy of your model.

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata <app-name> --indent=2

or create a folder to put the result in

$ python manage.py dumpdata <app-name> --indent=2  > [project]/[app]/[folder]/file-name.json
```

later you can use data upload to rebuild the original model.

Comment: Not what I was looking for but helpful.